# After building tor source package to run Tor on Raspberry Pi 3 apt-get offers upgrade

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, update, tor-install

Got a new RP3 with jessie and followed advice here (see "How to run Tor on Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi") to build from deb.tpo using the documentation on Tor's page about building Debian packages.

What is apt-get upgrade doing - the name seems identical: tor (0.2.8.6-2~d80.jessie+1)? Will it upgrade the binary or the source package?

This may be a very basic question, but I don't want to wreck a working Tor relay!

Thanks

Comment: With the Raspberry Pi B 2 and newer, you don't need to build from source anymore. You can use the package from the official repository. I'm not sure what apt-get will do, but I'd recommend installing via apt-get to make upgrades easier.